# Java SpringSecurity automatic login with HTML GET parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to make an automatic login into web application, which will be accessible on company's intranet.

The login will function in a way that when user is accessing the application, he will automatically send its credentials (username and password), example (company.com/myapplication/login?user=jhon&pass=123).

How can I implement that instead standard Spring Security login using HTML forms? Maybe using hidden form which will be then filled with GET parameters? I can't find any examples for that scenario.

My part is only after user has sent the link with parameters.

Comment: One of the main reason you can't find any scenario like this is that it is a huge security hole ! You should really avoid transmitting password as a clear url parameter.

Comment: Yes,that is correct. Actually , I was not clear. I am not really transmitting username and password ,that was just an example. I am really getting user number(base64) and timestamp (base64) and combination of those two encoded with secret key which I am checking on server side with secret key. If that is correct, I am fetching user corresponding to that number, his data and his role from my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this is two ways (or more). *(after our comment, it seams that you need to go with way two, because you do not have a username and password)*

**First way:**

Use the standard spring form login and then modify you application so that is send login request like the normal web form login would do.

Assume you have configured the `login-processing-url="/login/j_spring_security_check"`

```
<security:form-login
     login-processing-url="/login/j_spring_security_check"
     login-page="/login"
     authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
```

then send a

HTTP POST to `https://yourApplication/login/j_spring_security_check` with the two POST parameters

```
 j_username=<login>
 j_password=<password>
```

**Second way**:

Write your own Authentication Processing filter. That is a class that extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and it is responsible for

- taking stuff that the user used to authenticate (normally username and password) from the request,
- forming some the users authentication token object from them (for example an `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`)
- and invoking `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication authentication)` with this authentication token

To register your filter, you only need to add them to the spring security filter chain:

```
<security:custom-filter ref="yourFilter" after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
```

I recommend to have a view on the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFitler` (and keep in mind that is extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`) - this will explain it best.

If you do not have an username and password, then you need to create your own token (extends `Authentication`) and then you have to implement your own `AuthenticationProvider` (and register with the AuthenticationManager).  A `AuthenticationProvider` is reponsible to
 - consume an (special type of) Authentication Token and
 - validating that the stuff in the Authentication Token is valid
 - creating an OTHER `Authentication` object with `UserDetails` and Privileges
 - or, if the Authentication Token is not valid, throwing an `AuthenticationException`

Have a look at `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider` and its subclass, for an example.